# Форма в админке без модели с БД

Tags: django, django-admin

Нужна форма в админке. Для начала 2 поля `bool` и `int`, потом еще что-нибудь добавится.

Таблица в БД не нужна, данные для заполнения этих полей хотелось бы самому брать например из файла. Сохранять тоже самому в файл.

Как реализовать?

Примерная модель:

```
class SystemModel(models.Model):
    reboot_allowed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    reboot_timeout = models.IntegerField(default=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужны модели. Создайте простой класс с двумя простыми полями. Сериализуйте его в файл и десереализуйте его из файла при помощи JSON, XML или что вам больше по душе.

Возникает некоторая путаница из-за того, что использовано слово "модель", хотя это не "модель в MVC", а "сущность в БД". Моделью же на самом деле может быть любой класс.

См. [Django MVC pattern for non database driven models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290891/django-mvc-pattern-for-non-database-driven-models/1290978#1290978)